# Google's People API -- Issues Updating Contacts (Python)

Tags: google-people-api

I have the resourceName and etag of the person I wish to update, but I can't understand the documentation to actually execute the update.

I've looked at the API Documentation, and I feel like I'm structuring everything correctly. However, I keep getting Error 400 responses of two types:

1)

> https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/c1596007341306697743:updateContact?updatePersonFields=%7B%27emailAddresses%27%3A+%5B%7B%27value%27%3A+%27hello%40gmail.com%27%7D%5D%7D&alt=json
>   returned "Invalid value at 'update_person_fields'
>   (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.FieldMask), Field
>   'update_person_fields', Invalid FieldMask '{'emailAddresses':
>   [{'value': 'hello@gmail.com'}]}'. Map keys should be represented as
>   ["some_key"].">

2)

> https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/c1596007341306697743:updateContact?updatePersonFields=%7B%27emailAddresses%27%3A+%7B%27value%27%3A+%27hello%40gmail.com%27%7D%7D&alt=json
>   returned "Invalid updatePersonFields mask path: "{'email_addresses':
>   {'value': 'hello@gmail.com'}}". Valid paths are documented at
>   https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/updateContact.">

The first happens when the list brackets ([ ]) are left in the updatePersonFields parameter, the second when they are taken away.

I'm doing my best to implement this entirely in Python, and succeeded with both looking at and creating contacts. It seems that the update call is somehow different than the others. Any and all input is welcomed and appreciated.

```
    profileCode = "people/blahblahblah" 
    accessToken = "%Eblahblahblah=" 

    update = API.people().updateContact(
        resourceName=profileCode,
        body={"resourceName":profileCode, "etag":accessToken},
        updatePersonFields={"emailAddresses":[{"value":"hello@gmail.com"}]}
        ).execute()
```

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? What property do you want to update?

Comment: @Tanaike, it was a problem with the updatePersonFields parameter as Amos Yuen pointed out.

Comment: Thank you for your additional information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please look at the example in the documentation https://developers.google.com/people/v1/write-people#update-an-existing-contact.

`updatePersonFields` is just a comma separated list of the fields that should be updated e.g. `emailAddresses,names`. You're trying to specify the contact to update in the `updatePersonFields` param, that should be specified in the HTTP post body, not the `updatePersonFields` param.

Comment: Thank you! After moving the dictionary element to the body, I also had to make the updatePersonFields parameter a string as opposed to a list with a single element. Otherwise it responds with the first error from the OP.

Comment: that page is no longer active. do you have an example of the code you used?